# How to block remote requests

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

In our WordPress theme we check the user license with a **`wp_remote_get()`** request. Now some users reported back that they host didn't allow remote requests. My question is how can i test this myself locally for the development, how can i simulate to block remote get request.

Searched a lot but found nothing that works.

I use Apache, php and MySQL (latest versions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My best try would be to edit the hostfile. For Mac the hostfile is located at

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

And then i would add the following line and save.

```
169.254.1.1  yourdomain.com
```

To recreate your users problems.